# Сan't remove duplicates from the table ClickHouse

Tags: duplicates, clickhouse

We have a replicated shard table, on the engine ReplicatedMergeTree. Now on one shard (3 in total) in the table there are 484 million rows, about 21GB.

Engine deduplication does not work on that many lines, optimization also hangs.

Maybe someone came across a similar one and somehow solved this problem?

Comment: but ReplicatedMergeTree does not collapse rows. Replacing does. Or do you mean `optimize ... deduplicate` ?

Comment: yes, you are right